# Defining OBJECT-TYPE using syntax of another object

Tags: snmp, mib, ietf

I am new in SNMP and writing MIBs. I want to define OBJECT-TYPE but using syntax and other properties of another Object.

I searched about and find REFERENCE property, but due to this [link](https://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/ietf/smi-dt/issues.html) section 19, this prop. is only contains textual info and you must define SYNTAX and other properties of your object. I mean somehow similar to inheritance properties of other object.

Is there a way to achieve this?
regards.

Comment: "I mean somehow similar to inheritance properties of other object." That was never supported.